# SSRS how to use If and format statement together for negative values

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am trying to display seconds as minutes. Sometimes the value I get is negative. This causes problems. I wanted to check if the value is negative so that I can assign a default value. But I can not get If and Format statement work together.

This is what I have done to display the values without converting into minutes:

```
=Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value
```

[image]

This is what I have done to convert the seconds into minutes:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value, "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

[image]

This is the code I used to add a condition:

```
=IIF(Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value < 0, 0, Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value, "00:00"), "mm:ss"))
```

As you can see the if statement does not work as desired.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #Error is caused due to SSRS evaluate the whole `IIF()` expression before the `IIF` logic flow, so even if you are handling the negative values it checks both branches for errors.

Try using this expression:

```
=IIF(
  Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value < 0, 0,
  Format(
    DateAdd("s",IIF(Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value<0,0,Fields!RateLossSeconds.Value),"00:00"),
    "mm:ss"
  )
)
```

It checks if there is a negative value in the False branch of the first IIF().
In this case I replace the negative values by zero but you can use any value you want to.

Let me know if this helps.